# Read int from bytestring

Tags: haskell

How can I get Int from the bytestring:

```
let val_hex = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "\xcd"
let val_dig = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "\205"
val_hex == val_dig -- True
let maybeInt = Data.ByteString.Char8.readInt val_hex -- gets Nothing
```

So, I want do restore the value, packed to bytestring. i.e. maybeInt should be Maybe (205, "")

Comment: What you are trying to do is getting the character code of `\xcd` or `\205`, and that can be done using `fromEnum`. Try this: `fromEnum (Data.ByteString.Char8.head val_hex)`. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: You can convert ByteStrings in to `[Word8]` using `unpack`. After that it's just a matter of what each `Word8` means to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readInt` function is intended to read an integer encoded as an ASCII string from a (typically multi-byte) byte string, like this:

```
> let b = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "12345"
> b
"12345"
> Data.ByteString.Char8.readInt b
Just (12345,"")
>
```

It looks like you want to extract an integer from a single-byte byte string, where the integer is just the value of the byte.  The most straightforward way is probably to use `Data.ByteString.head`:

```
> let b = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "\xcd"
> Data.ByteString.head b
205
> :t Data.ByteString.head b 
Data.ByteString.head b :: GHC.Word.Word8
>
```

Note that this is `head` from `Data.ByteString` which returns `Word8`, not `Data.ByteString.Char8.head` which returns a `Char`.  As a general rule, functions in `Data.ByteString.Char8` treat a byte string as if it's ASCII encoded, while functions in `Data.ByteString` just treat it as a bunch of bytes with values from 0-255.  Most programs that manipulate byte strings as ASCII will need to use functions from both modules.

Since `Data.ByteString.head` returns a `Word8`, you may need to convert it using `fromIntegral` to the integer type that you want:

```
> replicate (fromIntegral (Data.ByteString.head b)) '*'
"*** ... 205 asterisks ... ***"
>
```

Comment: Oh, Gosh! I really didn't see the difference between ASCII and Word8 interpretations! Thanks a lot for explanation! In my opinion it is hard to infer this from haddock.